# After reinstalling R, I got error messenger to reinstall a bunch of packages one by one

Tags: r

I have recently reinstalled the R program (4.0.1 (2020-06-06)).

Ever since then, I got error messenger such as

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FlowSOM’:
> package ‘pillar’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

It tells me to install different packages one by one, like "pillar" above, so I have been re-installing them, and it's taking forever. With every loading action, I get the same multiple warnings.

I tried reinstalling R and RStudio. What else can I try?

Comment: What version did you have before updating R?

Answer (score 1):

After R upgrade there is sometimes necessary to rebuild installed packages with [`update.packages()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/update.packages.html):

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE,
                checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

That's because some packages need to be rebuild under a newer version of R. If you don't want to bother with this complications in the future, consider using [installr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/) package:

```
# for the first time
install.packages("installr")

# when you want to update R
installr::updateR()
```

This will update R and copy and rebuild all the packages for you.